# tcsh shell not autocompleting *.log files for vi

Tags: autocomplete, tcsh

When trying to autocomplete a file name for vi, files ending in .log are not listed as options.  How can I correct this?

Comment: What does the command `complete vi` output?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have somewhere (maybe in your `~/.cshrc`) specified something like this:

```
complete vi 'n/*/f:^*.{o,a,dvi,gz,z,Z,log}/'
```

You should change it (resp. override it), e.g.:

```
complete vi 'n/*/f:^*.{o,a,dvi,gz,z,Z}/'
```

Explanation: `n` means "Next-word completion", `*` is a glob-pattern to match the beginning of the word on the command line, `f` means filename, `^*.{o,a,dvi,gz,z,Z}` means that the filename must not end with `.o`, `.a`, `.dvi`, `.gz`, `.z` or `.Z`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the autocomplete which is ignoring the filenames ending with `.log` is not specific to `vi`.  It is possible that filenames ending with `.log` are not being autocompleted for anything.

There is a shell variable in tcsh called `fignore`, which, [according to the `man` page for `tcsh`](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Special_shell_variables.html#fignore), does the following:

> Lists file name suffixes to be ignored by completion.

In my own `tcsh` configuration and usage, it makes sense for me to ignore certain files with respect to completion capabilities:

```
% set fignore = (.aux .log .elc .o)
% echo $fignore
.aux .log .elc .o
```

Assuming, however, that you do have some `vi`-specific completion capabilities set up to ignore `.log`, the following command should be able to let you know:

```
% complete | grep vi
```